# How to open .jpeg files from various directories in Android?

Tags: android, android-cursor, android-file

I am developing a camera application. I want to list all files from Camera dir, DCIM dir, and my own app dir, I am using a grid view to show all these files. I have tried this code.

```
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {"Camera","DCIM","100MEDIA",
            "MyDirectory"};

    Cursor mCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, mProjection,
            selection, selectionArgs, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN);

    mCursor.moveToLast();
    if (mCursor!= null) {

        while (mCursor.moveToPrevious()) {

            int columnIndex = mCursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
            String imageID = mCursor.getString(columnIndex);

            // Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
            // MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            // Integer.toString(imageID) );
            // String url = uri.toString();

            img_path.add(imageID);

        }
    }

    mCursor.close();
}
```

This code works fine ,but it **does not list files from "Mydirectory"** that is created by me. I want to show the files from that directory also for editing purpose. Can anyone suggest another method or solution to this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Jaxon, are there any case issues I see you use MyDirectory and Mydirectory? Or is it just a pseudonym

Comment: No, it is not the problem  :), It is just a typing mistake. :)

Comment: Don't ask the MediaStore to list them for you. List them your self with the File class.

Answer (score 0):

Your app asks for jpg-files that the media scanner has found (  `getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI...)` )

Depending on which android version you are using and which file permissions the folder `MyDirectory` has the media scanner will not find the jpg files at all or with some delay ...

```
 > Can anyone suggest another method or solution to this problem?
```

If you are using `File.listFiles()` this issue should not exist.

Other apps address this issue by putting their own images into a sub-folder of DCIM so media scanner and other apps have no problems with read-permissions:

- /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera
- /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/MyDirectory

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. So where should I use File.listFiles() function ?? it is not understood .Can you help me?